# Copying part of an object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to copy a part of an object in illustrator?

I do not know the technical name of the effect I need to do, so I have to describe it. **I need to do the effect where you have an image and then you have a square on the image and a couple lines connecting to a zoomed in shot of that square** (if there is a name for this effect, that would be helpful too, since I can;t serach for it otherwise).

I have the larger image, but I cannot figure out any way to select a region, copy just that part, and be able to edit it (add features, adjust scale, etc.) to make the detailed view. I cannot find any way to cut up an image at all, in fact. Obviously artboards are not the way to go, since I am trying to make a compound image, not merely restrict the output when I go to JPEG format at the end. How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

1. Take the source layer and make a copy of it.
2. Take the copy and add a mask to it.  This is done from the transparency window.  Doing this will make it disappear temporarily.
3. From the transparency window, you will click on the "mask".  Now you're in a different set of layers.
4. Create a white square over the copied layer (where the image was earlier).
5. Changing the size of the square (the mask) will alter what's viewed.  Clicking back on the thumbnail of the image will take you to the regular layer mode
6. On the transparency window you will see a chain link, unclick this.  Now you can move/resize the copied layer inside of the mask.
7. Next, draw lines from the corners to the parts of the image you intend to designate "zoomed in"